# Escaping MYSQL command lines via Bash Scripting

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, escaping, sh

PHP has `mysql_real_escape_string()` to correctly escape any characters that might cause problems. What is the best way to mimic this functionality for BASH?

Is there anyway to do prepared mysql statements using bash? This seems to be the best way.

Most of my variables won't (shouldn't) have special characters, however I give the user complete freedom for their password. It may include characters like ' and ".

I may be doing multiple SQL statements so I'll want to make a script that takes in parameters and then runs the statement. This is what I have so far:

doSQL.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

SQLUSER="root"
SQLPASS="passwor339c"
SQLHOST="localhost"

SQL="$1"
SQLDB="$2"


if [ -z "$SQL" ]; then echo "ERROR: SQL not defined"; exit 1; fi
if [ -z "$SQLDB" ]; then SQLDB="records"; fi

echo "$SQL" | mysql -u$SQLUSER -p$SQLPASS -h$SQLHOST $SQLDB
```

and an example using said command:

example.sh:

```
PASSWORD=$1
doSQL "INSERT INTO active_records (password) VALUES ('$PASSWORD')"
```

Obviously this would fail if the password password contained a single quote in it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Bash, `printf` can do the escaping for you:

```
$ a=''\''"\;:#[]{}()|&^$@!?, .<>abc123'
$ printf -v var "%q" "$a"
$ echo "$var"
\'\"\\\;:#\[\]\{\}\(\)\|\&\^\$@\!\?\,\ .\<\>abc123
```

I'll leave it to you to decide if that's aggressive enough.

Comment: This seems to fail when given $# in the `a` variable.

Comment: @BHare: It works for me: `a='$#'; printf ...; echo ...` gives me `\$#`. What do you get? I can't tell how it "seems to fail" unless you tell me.

Comment: I realized it was interpolating $# because I was using double-quotes.

Comment: you will have problems when escaping utf8 characters, it will give \302240 for the utf &nbsp; , and it can give you a lot of trouble.

Comment: If you're facing the issue that it adds a $ before, it's very easy to go away of it with something like:
`printf -v CMD_ESCAPED %q "$CMD_RESULT"
CMD_ESCAPED="${CMD_ESCAPED:1}"`

After that it works very well

Comment: `you will have problems when escaping utf8 characters` I do not think that is true. I tested `mysql ... -e 'select * from job where name = '"'$(printf "%q" "$(printf "\ua0")")'" db` and it worked, but I do not know anything about "connection/database character set" to be sure.

Answer (score 6):

There is no escape from the following construct, no matter what quotes you use:

```
function quoteSQL() {
    printf "FROM_BASE64('%s')" "$(echo -n "$1" | base64 -w0 )"
}

PASSWORD=$1
doSQL "INSERT INTO active_records (password) VALUES ($(quoteSQL "$PASSWORD"));"

# I would prefer piping
printf 'INSERT INTO active_records (password) VALUES (%s);\n' $(quoteSQL "$PASSWORD") | doSQL
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a classic case of using the wrong tool for the job.

You've got a *lot* of work ahead of you to implement the escaping done by `mysql_real_escape_string()` in bash. Note that `mysql_real_escape_string()` actually delegates the escaping to the MySQL library which takes into account the connection and database character sets. It's called "real" because its predecessor `mysql_escape_string()` did not take the character set into consideration, and could be tricked into injecting SQL.

I'd suggest using a scripting language that has a MySQL library, such as Ruby, Python, or PHP.

If you insist on bash, then use the [MySQL Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) syntax.

Comment: I don't know ruby or python, I run PHP as a apache lib so no CLI. I suppose I could use PERL, but I hate mixing PERL and BASH. Everything else the script is doing is in BASH.

Comment: Would prepared statements really make any difference? You still need to pass values to mysql before you can prepare a statement.

Comment: Link is broken, replace with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` of course only escapes a single string literal to be quoted, not a whole statement.  You need to be clear what purpose the string will be used for in the statement.  According to the MySQL manual section on [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html), for inserting into a string field you only need to escape single and double quotation marks, backslashes and NULs.  However, a bash string cannot contain a NUL, so the following should suffice:

```
#escape for MySQL single string
PASSWORD=${PASSWORD//\\/\\\\}
PASSWORD=${PASSWORD//\'/\\\'}
PASSWORD=${PASSWORD//\"/\\\"}
```

If you will be using the string after a `LIKE`, you will also probably want to escape `%` and `_`.

Prepared statements are another possibility.  And make sure you don't use `echo -e` in your bash.

See also https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

This will escape apostrophes

```
a=$(echo "$1" | sed s/"'"/"\\\'"/g)
```

Please note though that mysql_real_escape_string also escapes \x00, \n, \r, \, " and \x1a. Be sure to escape these for full security.

To escape \x00 for example:

```
a=$(echo "$1" | sed s/"\x00"/"\\\'"/g)
```

With a bit of effort you can probably escape these using one sed command.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not just use the real thing?

> **A script, anywhere, such as** 
>   ~/scripts/mysqli_real_escape.php

```
#!/bin/php
<?php

$std_input_data = '';
$mysqli             = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'database_name');

if( ftell(STDIN) !== false  )       $std_input_data = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
if( empty($std_input_data)  )       exit('No input piped in');
if( mysqli_connect_errno( ) )       exit('Could not connect to database');

fwrite  (   STDOUT, 
            $mysqli->real_escape_string($std_input_data) 
        );

exit(0);

?>
```

> Next, run from bash terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/script/mysqli_real_escape.php`
ln -s ~/script/mysqli_real_escape.php /usr/bin/mysqli_real_escape
```

> All set! Now you can use `mysqli_real_escape` in your bash scripts!

```
#!/bin/bash
MyString="stringW@#)*special characters"
MyString="$(printf "$MyString" | mysqli_real_escape )"
```

Note: From what I understand, command substitution using `"$(cmd ..."$var")"` is preferred over using backticks. However, as no further nesting would be needed either should be fine.

Further Note: When inside command substitution, `"$(...)"`, a new quote context is created. This is why the quotes around variables do not screw up the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, where `my-file.txt` contains spaces, new lines and quotes:

```
IFS='' content=$(cat my-file.txt)
mysql <flags> -e "update table set column = $(echo ${content@Q} | cut -c 2-) where something = 123"
```

Comment: This doesn't work with input `echo "test" > my-file.txt` as it has an additional `'` in its output. -> `cut -c 2-` seems to cut the first single quote but leaves the last one. Just using `echo` to debug the substitutions or some `SELECT $(...);` if with `mysql -e` do show some dubious behaviour. Single quotes especially will be escaped weirdly with this and double quotes were not escaped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple Bash functions I wrote, grouped into a library.

It provides methods for proper quoting/escaping strings and identifiers:

```bash
##### db library functions #####

# Executes SQL Queries on localhost's MySQL server
#
# @Env
# $adminDBUser: The database user
# $adminDBPassword: The database user's password
#
# @Params
# $@: Optional MySQL arguments
#
# @Output
# >&1: The MySQL output stream
db::execute() {
  # Uncomment below to debug
  #tee --append debug.sql |
    mysql \
      --batch \
      --silent \
      --user="${adminDBUser:?}" \
      --password="${adminDBPassword:?}" \
      --host=localhost \
      "$@"
}

# Produces a quoted string suitable for inclusion in SQL statements.
#
# @Params
# $1: The string to bo quoted
#
# @Output
# >&1: The quoted identifier suitable for inclusion in SQL statements
db::quoteString() {
  local -- string="${1:?}"
  local -- bas64String && bas64String=$(printf %s "${string}" | base64)
  db::execute <<< "SELECT QUOTE(FROM_BASE64('${bas64String}'));"
}

# Produces a quoted identifier suitable for inclusion in SQL statements.
#
# @Params
# $1: The identifier to bo quoted
#
# @Output
# >&1: The quoted identifier suitable for inclusion in SQL statements
db::quoteIdentifier() {
  local -- identifier="${1:?}"
  local -- bas64Identifier && bas64Identifier=$(printf %s "${identifier}" | base64)
  db::execute <<< "SELECT sys.quote_identifier(FROM_BASE64('${bas64Identifier}'))"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This will work:

```
echo "John O'hara"  | php -R 'echo addslashes($argn);'
```

To pass it to a variable:

```
name=$(echo "John O'hara"  | php -R 'echo addslashes($argn);')
```