# How do I insert a special character such as ' into MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am executing the `insert` query from a shell script which reads data from multiple files. Some of the data to be inserted contains `'` in the text and MySQL keeps giving errors

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Development & Empowerment, Youth Affairs                 
','
Himachal Pradesh                    ' at line 1
```

This is the actual text: `Women's Development & Empowerment, Youth Affairs`.

Comment: this thread may help you : [Escaping MYSQL command lines via Bash Scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383135/escaping-mysql-command-lines-via-bash-scripting)

Comment: Its better if you escape ' character with ' than \. Its because some db ex: sqllite show error with \ escape character. You can write: "Women''s Development & Empowerment, Youth Affairs."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to escape the quote, like so:

```
'Women\'s Development & Empowerment, Youth Affairs'
```

Note, that if you're generating the SQL statement from a language like PHP, there are functions available to do this for you.

In PHP, for instance, there is [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), which takes care of it for you. Note, that prepared statements are to be prefered over this, as it's harder to get those wrong.

See also:

- [The MySQL manual entry on strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html)
- [PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: and use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for newer versions

Answer (score 3):

You will have to escape the input strings before passing them to MySql.

The [list of escape character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html)s is:

```
Character   Escape Sequence
\0  An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
\'  A single quote (“'”) character.
\"  A double quote (“"”) character.
\b  A backspace character.
\n  A newline (linefeed) character.
\r  A carriage return character.
\t  A tab character.
\Z  ASCII 26 (Control-Z). See note following the table.
\\  A backslash (“\”) character.
\%  A “%” character. See note following the table.
\_  A “_” character. See note following the table.
```

Comment: I use mysql 5.7 and \' have error in long text with collation uft8mb4, but \" has not error !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to escape the ' character with a backslash \

Women\'s Development & Empowerment, Youth Affairs

Comment: I have around 30k files and I do not want to use sed to have to do a find and replace. I would rather like to handle at the mysql end if it is possible.

Comment: You'll need to use a programming language or a do a find and replace over the file to replace ' with \'

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your quote.  You can do this by doubling it in your insert query; i.e. use '' rather than '.  That is two single quotes rather than a single double quote.

Answer (score 0):

What is the server side languge you using?

there are many methods through which you can escape string , i'll prefer that!

Eg: you can use `mysql_escape_string` the data you are entering in query so it will automatically escape charecters like `" ' "`

mysql_escape_string is a `php function` provided you are using `php`

Comment: I am trying process some files and push some data into mysql. I have written a small shell script for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying process some files and push some data into mysql. I have written a small shell script for this.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableName
 WHERE columnName REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```