# How can I submit symbols to php and update it

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How can I submit any kind of symbols to php and update it into my database tables? When I use some symbols `('!@#$%^&*()_+=),` it does not update the database table. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: `htmlentities()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Given that you have tagged this question both [tag:jquery] and [tag:mysql], when you say "*the data table*" are you referring to a jQuery data table or a MySQL data table?

Comment: `htmlentities`? What does HTML have to do with SQL? The OP just needs to use prepared statements and do proper error checking. But there's no way to answer a question that only says that some undisclosed code does not work.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803354/how-do-i-insert-a-special-character-such-as-into-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `htmlspecialchars()` in which you can find the documentation here.

http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: I used this in my php and it works well. Thanks 
define('CHARSET', 'ISO-8859-1');
define('REPLACE_FLAGS', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XHTML);

Answer (score 0):

Use function htmlentities()
The values will not be stored in the database as they are like ('!@#$%^&*()_+=) but this function will change your " to " and other characters respectively.

Keep aware yourself of SQL Injection and XSS. If you do not filter your inputs properly then your code will be vulnerable to script kiddies.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `htmlentities()` function. It's the best solution I think.
If you really really don't want to use this function for some reason you can always change the column type to `text` instead of `varchar`.

*Edit: sorry for using the wrong function. You guys are right. Maybe `mysql_real_escape_string()` does the job but probably it would only take care of the quotations.*

Comment: Database tables are not HTML documents. `htmlentities` is not appropriate.