# How to insert records with many special characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have to update many database records that have two columns; `id` and `content`.

The problem is that `content` can contain any number of words and special characters and I want `MySQL` to understand, that everything in the field, between the very first and last double quotes (`"`), is an string, e.g.:

```
(1823423, "blabla <script type"something/something> somettext '_' " 
 + " and more text + more special characters")
```

As I have about 5k similar records to update and this script can't be changed like adding escape characters (`\"`), because it would stop working.

Comment: So what is the problem? Can you add the special characters? Maybe use `CHAR(ascii number)`

Comment: Is this sample code ``(1823423, "blabla <script type"something/something> somettext '_' " 
  + " and more text + more special characters")`` is an example of entry of your table or something else?

Comment: Problem is, that mysql things that column ends after second " from text, which is just small part of whole column content

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803354/how-do-i-insert-a-special-character-such-as-into-mysql

Comment: @Laiso it's a part of example string that i want to insert into DB

Comment: @Amol Raje As i mentioned in question, if I put anything that negates special character inside script it would stop working.. so i can't just \ all special characters. I just want to show sql that everything that is between first " and last " is a string

Comment: you need  `mysql_real_escape_string()`  like function which is in php it will handle the special characters.

Comment: @harcotlupus Please take a look at this documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

You need use `CONCAT` and escape the caracters with `\`

I guess you need something like this

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/MAVP18973)**

```
SELECT CONCAT("blabla script type\"something/something\"> somettext '_' " ,
              " and more text + more special characters") as t
```