# Escape SQL with bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, escaping

I'm working on importing data into MySQL from two business systems. I've written some bash scripts to compare the differences between the systems in order to only import the relevant parts. Now I need to construct SQL queries so I can load the data. My main problem is to escape single quotes, I've added the code part below that should escape it, but somehow that is only done sometimes, inconsistent. I don't get it...

```
TEXT=${PART[1]/\'/\\\'}
```

So... Are there any better ways / programs I can pipe data through that escapes the data? The absolutely best solution would be to use MySQL's `load data infile` mixed with `on duplicate update`, but if I understand correct, that has not yet been implemented.

Comment: You could use `mysqlimport` with the [`--replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_replace) option (or `LOAD DATA REPLACE ...`).

Comment: In particular, see the last sentence in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383778/26428).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: How do you propose passing prepared statement parameters from BASH?  If commands are piped to `mysql`, one would have to use `EXECUTE stmt USING ...` in which the parameters would still have to be escaped; and if one has access to the C API to pass them directly over that, one could also have just used [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html)...

Comment: @eggyal: Oh, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is probably not the right tool to do it, but to make your approach at least a bit more correct, you could try

```
TEXT=${PART[1]//\'/\\\'}
```

i.e. use double slash to repeat the substitution.

Quoting `man bash`:

> If pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced  with 
>   string

Answer (score 1):

Use [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) with Python and use prepared statements (parameterized queries).

Note the [use of a comma](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples) between the select statement and the data tuple instead of a percent sign. You want to let the module do the string substitution rather than Python.

```
c=db.cursor()
max_price=5
c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast
          WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "aaa''bbb" | sed "s/'/\\\'/g"

aaa\'\'bbb
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this was helpful for what I was wanting (which was to escape single quotes).