# insert html contents in to mysql from .txt file

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I have 1000's of `HTML` newsletters all sequentialy numbered 1.txt 2.txt
I am building a new cms way for staff to edit so I want the content in to the DB `(mysql)`

I was trying to run a bash script

```
array..

for i in "${array[@]}"

do
```

:

```
value=`cat ../data/"$i".txt`

mysql -u$MYUSER -p$MYPASS "cms" -se "UPDATE nl SET site_html = '$value', update_date=TIMESTAMP(NOW()) WHERE sid ='$i' "
```

done

but the html seems to explode the update statement

Comment: Don't it need to be escaped?

Comment: I can't escape the $value cause it's in '' within "" unless I can escape everything before putting it in or sanitise the variable or the file first maybe?

Comment: You must double up (escape) the single-quotes in $value before you use it in the SQL string. Something like `${value//'/''}` instead of just `$value`.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383994/1275256

Comment: will try that gknicker i was about to SED every file and encode all the html

Answer (score 0):

You must double up (escape) the single-quotes in `$value` before you use it in the SQL string:

```
"UPDATE nl SET site_html = '${value//'/''}', update_date=TIMESTAMP(NOW()) WHERE sid ='$i' "
```

Otherwise any single quotes in the HTML cause the SQL string to terminate prematurely, which will certainly result in (SQL injection) syntax errors.

Comment: so close i can nearly smell the bacon!
line 18: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Ok it's a syntax error in your bash script. I googled [unexpected EOF while looking for matching `](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=unexpected%20EOF%20while%20looking%20for%20matching%20%60) and found [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154427/unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching-bash-script) which may help finish this puppy off :)