# MySQL Set Password Via Command-Line Variable

Tags: mysql, bash

I need a one-liner to provision users in my databases. I'm running MySQL 5.6. Here is what I'm setting the password as a variable so that I can pass it dynamically (obviously it won't always be 'password').

```
mysql_password="password"
mysql -u ted -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'ted'@'localhost' = PASSWORD($mysql_password);"
```

I'm getting the following error when I run this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password)' at line 1
```

**What is wrong with the statement? Can it be corrected or is another solution available so I accomplish this via Bash?**

Comment: It's a string inside the `SET PASSWORD` statement, and therefore needs to be surrounded with single quotes when you pass it in, just like `'ted'` is.  Be careful though, this is not injection-safe.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383135/escaping-mysql-command-lines-via-bash-scripting

Comment: But single quotes doesn't imterpret variables in bash.

Comment: The outer string is still double quoted. You just need the single quotes inside. Example `var=astring; echo "Variable is '$var'"` will print `"Variable is 'astring'"` in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround the variable by single quotes:

```
mysql -u root -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'ted'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('$mysql_password');"
```